# conjugation by quasi-conformal maps and convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f_n$ a sequence of quasi-conformal automorphisms of $\mathbb C$ and $g$ an element of $PSL_2(\mathbb C)$ if we have that $f_ng f_n^{-1}$ converges to $fgf^{-1}$ for $f$ quasi-conformal as well, can we conclude that $f_n$ converge to $f$ up to an element $h$ of $PSL_2(\mathbb C)$ commuting with $g$, i.e. $f_n\rightarrow h f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can find qc homeos $f_n$ that commute with $g$ but such that the $f_n$ have greater and greater distortion and do not converge.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that. Do you know how to construct explicit examples?

Comment: Sure, take $f_n(x+iy)=x+niy$: it commutes with $g(z)=z+1$ and the $f_n$ do not converge